# how to run spark to read from json file and display content?

Tags: apache-spark

the spark_job.py file has this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, LongType, DecimalType,StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

def readMyStream(rdd):
  if not rdd.isEmpty():
    df = spark.read.json(rdd)
    print('Started the Process')
    print('Selection of Columns')
    df = df.select('t1','t2','t3','timestamp').where(col("timestamp").isNotNull())
    df.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    spark = SparkSession(sc)
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

    stream_data = ssc.textFileStream("jsondata.json")
    stream_data.foreachRDD( lambda rdd: readMyStream(rdd) )
    ssc.start()
    ssc.stop()
```

the jsondata.json file has this:

```
[{"timestamp": "1571053218000","t1": "55.23","t2": "10","t3": "ON"},

{"timestamp": "1571053278000","t1": "63.23","t2": "11","t3": "OFF"},

{"timestamp": "1571053338000","t1": "73.23","t2": "12","t3": "ON"},

{"timestamp": "1571053398000","t1": "83.23","t2": "13","t3": "ON"}]
```

running:

```
python spark_job.py
```

just gives me this:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\madi_kafka> SUCCESS: The process with PID 10272 (child process of PID 2544) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2544 (child process of PID 10652) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 10652 (child process of PID 4516) has been terminated.
```

Comment: it's not "just" text, it's a structured JSON, thus use `spark.readStream \
  .format("json")         
  .option()
  .schema(my_schema)
  .load("path/to/data")` - and yes, this would be Scala. Do you need a stream? If not, you can try in Python `spark.read.schema(schema).json(inputPath)` - otherwise, you should still use the JSON loader and not a plain text file reader

Comment: @UninformedUser , thx but what is schema in my case, i just dont have this schema

Comment: I think you can just omit the schema. As you already did in your separate method. Still not sure, do you rally need a stream here? I mean, you're basically reading from a static file, no? Or is this just for testing and a JSON stream will be provided later on?

Comment: @UninformedUser, yes, it's a static file, i m trying to make ANY basic example run and can't lol, i m actually doing something diff - i have a stream of comments to process(count top10 words)

Answer (score 1):

***show*** function can help you,I think this code example could help you to solve your problem:

```
val data = session.sqlContext.read.format("json").load("data/input.json")
val first = data.show()
```

Most of time spark could find your the schema of your data implicitly.

Comment: thx, but it s not complete code, i do know about show()

Answer (score 0):

I use below code in scala,I think it could be helpful :

```
import session.implicits._
case class TClass(timestamp:String,t1:String,t2:String,t3:String)
val jsonData= session.read.option("inferSchema","true").option("multiline","true").option("header","true").json("data/jsondata.json").as[TClass]
jsonData.printSchema()
jsonData.show()
print("Started the Process")
print("Selection of Columns")
val df = jsonData.select("timestamp","t1","t2","t3").where(col("timestamp") isNotNull)
df.show()
```

and get this out:

```
+-------------+-----+---+---+
|    timestamp|   t1| t2| t3|
+-------------+-----+---+---+
|1571053218000|55.23| 10| ON|
|1571053278000|63.23| 11|OFF|
|1571053338000|73.23| 12| ON|
|1571053398000|83.23| 13| ON|
+-------------+-----+---+---+
```

I wish it could be helpful for you.